# X11 keeps crashing with "Cannot establish any listening sockets", I cleared /tmp but it still crashes

Tags: crash, x11

Started X11 on Lion today, now it keeps crashing over and over - can't get it to stop.

> Cannot establish any listening sockets

1) is there any way to stop this over and over again?

2) is there a fix for it?

I cleared /tmp/.X11-unix and /tmp/.X0-lock